# Secondary HDD doesn't show up but reappears out of nowhere (windows 10)

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-10

So I built a new PC a few months ago and I've been having problems with my secondary hard drive since. At first the harddrive would show up but wasn't allocated. Allocating it worked for a while but there was some kind of malfunction or error and it seemingly disappeared from file explorer. Looking in disk manager showed it as offline, unallocated and the available space was wrong. I tried to allocate it but it would be unable to every time. I used various HDD wizards to try and sort it out but nothing worked.

I gave up for a while but eventually tried changing which sata port it was using on the mobo and it showed up on boot up. I allocated it and it worked for about a week. Now when I boot up my PC, it isn't in file explorer or disk manager, BUT for whatever reason, it will show up and be usable while I'm in the middle of a game. Specifically, Counter Strike. It doesn't matter how much time has passed since I booted it up, it could be 5 minutes or 12 hours, as soon as I'm in the middle of a game of CS, it forces a tab out and file explorer has opened up to my secondary HDD. Now, it doesn't show up all the time, but when it does it's exclusively when I'm playing CS.

I have no idea why it's doing this and it's frustrating because my SSD is full. Nothing on the HDD relates to CS:GO. When it does shop up, it's shown as healthy and scanning it for errors show's nothing. Any idea what's up with it? It's such a specific case I can't find anything else online.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to really figure out the problem is to have some spare parts laying around.

1. I would change out the power supply with something that has a bit more wattage, and see if that doesn't sort out the issue.
2. I would change the drive with a spare one you have laying around. If the spare works fine, then RMA the hard drive. If the drive has issues similar to the original (2nd drive) then something is either wrong with your power or the motherboard.
3. It could be a motherboard issue, maybe update the bios. Or check for updated drivers. Never install motherboard drivers from the cd. always check the motherboards's manufacture website for the newest updated drivers.

Comment: Power supply isn't an issue, my PSU is 1000w. I don't have a spare drive around unfortunately. I updated my drivers and the drive appeared. I restarted my PC and it's disappeared again.

Comment: The PSU might also be faulty. You never know.